# Sorting 2d array according examples

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Im having huge though time trying to resolve this.

How its suppose to work? Basicly the user inputs the length and the width of the array. And then chooses where he wants the X on the array. Basicly like the minesweeper game. Here is an example!

```
Example #1

Input
1. 3 //length
2. 5 //width
3. {1}
4. {1}

Return
{{X, 1, 2},
{1, 2, 3},
{2, 3, 4},
{3, 4, 5},
{4, 5, 6}}

Example #2
1. 5
2. 7
3. {2, 4}
4. {3, 7}

Return
{{3, 2, 3, 4, 5}
{2, 1, 2, 3, 4}
{1, X, 1, 2, 3}
{2, 1, 2, 3 ,4}
{3, 2, 3, 2, 3}
{4, 3, 2, 1, 2}
{3, 2, 1, X ,1}}

EDIT: More easy example

input 3 length
input 3 width

cordinnates {1,1}

Return
{{X , 1 , 2}
 {1 , 2 , 3}
 {2 , 3 , 4}}
```

EDIT: The distance between two blocks is the sum of
their horizontal and vertical distance (a move in the diagonal direction is therefore considered a distance of 2).

And here is my Code! I cannot figure how to calculate the distance to the X on each number! Any help/tip?

```
public static int[][] getMapGrid(int cityLength, int cityWidth, int XCoordinates, int YCoordinates)
        {
            int contador = 0;
            bool vira = false;
            int[,] city = new int[cityLength,cityWidth];
            Console.WriteLine(city.Length);
            contador = cityWidth;
            city[XCoordinates, YCoordinates] = X;
            for (int a = 0; a < cityLength; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < cityWidth; b++)
                {
                    if (XCoordinates != b && YCoordinates != a)
                    {
                        if (vira != true)
                        {
                            city[a, b] = contador;
                            contador--;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            contador++;
                            city[a, b] = contador;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        vira = true;
                    }
                    Console.Write(city[a, b]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }

            Console.ReadLine();
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: How are you defining distance?

Comment: Im not, i really dont know where to define it... really dont know how to!

Comment: Well you're asking for the distance to the X. Is that a hypotenutal distance or the number of cells you need to jump to to get to the X? And if it's the number of cells, are diagonal jumps allowed? You need to figure this out before anyone can help you.

Comment: In other words, is the distance between `1,1` and `2,2` either one or two?

Comment: Also, what's with the second example having 2 Xs? You don't mention that scenario in your question. Should the number for each cell be the distance to the closest X? You haven't been very specific.

Comment: @itsme86 True, sorry i forgot to post it!! Going to edit it!

Comment: Maybe adding the manually calculated distance in your two examples we can understand better what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I see you've added information about deriving the distance. Still not sure what to do about multiple Xs.

Comment: @itsme86 The Xs are just to pinpoint the position on the array nothing more. When you pinpoint it, it must show the distance between the two blocks that is the sum of their horizontal and vertical distance. For example,

input 3 length
input 3 width

and the X coordinates can be {1,1}, it will appear on the screen
{X,1,2,
 1, 2, 3,
2, 3, 4}

Comment: Added a more easy example to understand

Comment: Because you aren't trying to get a true distance, all you need to do is subtract the absolute value of the difference between the starting and ending position's X value, do the same for the Y, then add the 2 values together. (1,2) to (4,5) would be a distance of abs(4-1) xdiff + abs(5-2) ydiff = 6 total.

Comment: The type of distance you are looking for is called [Manhatten Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhatten_distance).

Comment: In example 2, can you explain what `{2, 4}` and `{3, 7}` means. I was thinking it was the position of each `X` assuming top left is `{1, 1}`but that is not the case as x are at `{2, 3}` and `{4, 7}`. **Thus it is hard to understand what you are trying to do as there are no consistency between your 3 examples (first one as a single number between { and } and only the second has different values for X and Y). Even worst, there is almost no useful information to explain what it does. The only thing I have deduce is that the numbers in the array seems to be the Manhatten distance to the nearest X.

Comment: @Phil1970 That was to pinpoint instead of only one X, two X's. One had 2 on Xcoordinates and 3 on YCoordinates and the other had 4 on XCoordinates and 7 on Ycoordinates

Comment: @V.David He means that above you have the coordinate `{2, 4}` but the X in the related output is positioned at what seems to be `{2, 3}`, as well as `{3, 7}` referring to an X that seems to be on `{4, 7}`. Is that a typo or are we misunderstanding something?

Comment: Okay, I see. Parameter 3 in the example is a list of X coordinates, and parameter 4 is a corresponding list of Y coordinates. That is an incredibly confusing convention to use, and you should have explained that clearly from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your method is returning an `int[][]`. Since you are dealing with a set width and height, you can optimize by using a square array instead of a jagged array (i.e. `int[,]`). (I see that your code does indeed use a square array, so that's a typo you should probably fix sooner rather than later.)

Second, your input coordinates seem to be 1-based (as in, the top left coordinate is {1,1}). For the sake of your sanity, I would suggest that you instead use 0-based indices, since arrays you use will be 0-based as well. Otherwise, you would need to offset your coordinates every time you want to use them, which bogs down your code with unnecessary verbosity.

And third, you don't need to use complex pathfinding to determine each tile's distance from a point. Each of the points is known, the map lies on a uniform Cartesian grid, and none of the tiles introduce additional heuristics like obstacles or travel modifiers. In this case, you can just do a simple calculation for the [Manhatten Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) from the selected tile to the nearest specified point.

```
public int[,] BuildMap(int w, int h, int[] xList, int[] yList)
{
    if (xList.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("at least one coordinate pair must be supplied");
    if (xList.Length != yList.Length)
        throw new ArgumentException("coordinate lists must have equal length");

    int[,] map = new int[w, h];

    // Iterate over each map tile
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
        {
            // Set storage variable
            int temp = int.MaxValue;

            // Iterate over each point in x/y lists
            for (int idx = 0; idx < xList.Length; idx++)
            {
                // Find the nearest point
                // Distance = |x - px| + |y - py|
                temp = Math.Min(Math.Abs(x - xList[idx]) + Math.Abs(y - yList[idx]), temp);
            }

            // Assign the shortest distance
            map[x, y] = temp;
        }
    }

    return map;
}
```